# Convergence and not bounded sequence {$a_nb_n$}$_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help for the following task:

a) Let {$a_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence with $a_n$ $\neq 0$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$=0 and {$b_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a convergent real sequence with the limit b>0.

Show that the sequence {$a_nb_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded.

My approach: Well we know every convergent series is bounded. This means we have to prove that {$a_nb_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent. How do we do that? I am not sure. But we also have this knowledge, but I don't know if its helpful:

$1)$ Is {$a_n$} a sequence with |$a_n$|$\rightarrow \infty$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then $\frac{1}{a_n}$ $\rightarrow 0$ for  $n \rightarrow \infty$

$2)$Is {$b_n$} a sequence with $b_n \neq 0$, n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $b_n \rightarrow 0$ fr $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then $\frac{1}{|b_n|}$ $\rightarrow \infty$ for  $n \rightarrow \infty$

I am thankful for any advice

Answer (score 2):

Suppose otherwise that $(a_nb_n)$ is bounded. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=0$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}\cdot a_nb_n=0
$$
that is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0
$$
Therefore $b=0$, a contrdiction QED

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I am still unsure why lim 1/$a_n$ $\cdot$ $a_nb_n$= 0 should implicate that lim $b_n$=0. Could you explain that for me? I mean even if the limit of $b_n$ would be not zero, the equation would be zero...I am probably missing something..

Comment: @Analysis_Mark That's simply because $$\frac{a_n b_n}{a_n}=b_n$$

Comment: @Crostul But why do we need {$a_n$$b_n$} to be bounded, to follow that lim $\frac{1}{a_n} \cdot a_nb_n$=0. What is the purpose of saying them to are bounded.